# ¿Cómo se evalúa esta expresión?

Tags: c++

```
bool valor = 0<=50>=6;
```

Pensaba que la secuencia sería evaluar los valores dos a dos, es decir, se evalúa `0<=50`, lo cual es `true` y luego `50>=6`, lo que también es `true`, de forma que el valor final también es `true`, pero veo que no es así.

Entonces, ¿cómo se evaluaría una expresión así?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Pensaba que la secuencia sería evaluar los valores dos a dos, es decir, se evalúa 0<=50, lo cual es true y luego 50>=6, lo que también es true

En C++ las evaluaciones pueden ser unarias o binarias, es decir, pueden evaluar un término o dos... nunca tres o más:

```
bool flag = 5>6; // Evaluación binaria

if( flag ) // Evaluación unaria
{
}
```

En el caso que propones, y dado que las evaluaciones ternarias no existen, el equivalente sería el siguiente:

```
int a = 0 <= 50 ? 1 : 0;
bool valor = a>=6;
```

El procesador solo entiende de dígitos numéricos. Así, las condiciones falsas devuelven un 0 y las verdaderas un 1.

La primera condición que se encuentra el compilador es `0<=50`. Como la condición es cierta, el resultado devuelto será 1. Este valor se utiliza para la segunda condición, `1>=6`. Esta última condición es falsa, luego el resultado final será `false`.

Lo que tu pretendes hacer se soluciona utilizando operadores:

```
bool valor = (0>=50) && (50>=6);
```

Answer (score 5):

En la instrucción que comentas realmente estás haciendo 2 operaciones. 
Primero `0<=50` que devuelve `true(1)`.

La segunda que te hace es el equivalente a `(0<=50)>=6` lo cual te devuelve `false(0)`, realmente la comparación que te hace en el segundo caso es el resultado de `0<=50` comparandolo con el `6` = `1>=6` (teniendo en cuenta que `true = 1` y `false = 0`).